# How to move the login form to the header?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I need help in moving over the User login form to the header of the same page in Drupal 7. I am new to Drupal and I am not very familiar with the Drupal hooks yet. How should I achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far.

#### template.php

```
function bklyn_theme() {
  $items = array();
  // create custom user-login.tpl.php
  $items['user_login'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'bklyn') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'user-login',
  'preprocess functions' => array(
  'bklyn_preprocess_user_login'
  ),
 );
 
 $items['user_pass'] = array(
 'render element' => 'form',
 'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'bklyn') . '/templates',
 'template' => 'user-pass',
 'preprocess functions' => array(
 'bklyn_preprocess_user_pass'
 ),
 );
 
return $items;
}

function bklyn_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
  $vars['intro_text'] = t('Username');
}

function bklyn_preprocess_user_pass(&$vars) {
  $vars['intro_text'] = t('Password');
}
```

I am not sure how I can integrate the login to show up in the header.

### Before

[image: What is now]

### After

[image: How it should look and header region]

Comment: Are you speaking of the user login form located in `yourwebsite.com/user` ? or are you referring to the [user login block](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8InGT.jpg) that shows up on most pages ?

Comment: from the website/user. I need the logon to place on the header content area and be able to style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from the **website/user**. I need the logon to place on the header content
>   area and be able to style it.

All you have to do is edit your theme's **page.tpl.php**

Since the form gets displayed as the page content:

in the header section of your template file add:

```
<?php if (current_path() == 'user'): ?>
     <?php print render($page['content']);?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then find the original `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` and add:

```
  <?php if (current_path() != 'user'): ?>
     <?php print render($page['content']);?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

OR... do the `if (current_path() != 'user') {` for everything inside the `#main-wrapper`

OR... use the if statement to add a div class that will colour your #main-wrapper background to red.

Comment: Thanks! I have a question about the if statements. The if statements are part of php so why I need to place <?php ?> for the print?

Comment: It didn't work without the if statement in <?php and end if?>. I edited your code to reflect how it worked for me.

Comment: Because I copy pasted and did not realize my syntax was wrong.  If you `<?php` before the if and `?>` after the closing `}` tag (from my original answer) it should work, as long as you don't have any HTML in between. The way you did it, is one way to add HTML code in between.

Comment: Your way, is the popular way for doing templates as its more visually friendly and allows you to modify and add HTML easily if you need to.

Comment: Yes right now I am styling to my requirements but either way your suggestion worked perfect. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @PiotrJurski **PS:** [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/current_path/7.x) is a Drupal 7 API function which gets the current path, in case you were wondering where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need hooks to move the user login block to header. you can move the user login block to any region on the page. From block administer page move the login block to the header region.
save and logout to check it working.

Comment: Well actually its not the block. It's from website.com/user

Comment: Moving the block in the header region should do the job for you. Any specific reasons for moving a page inside a region??

Comment: I provided screenshots to better understand.

Comment: But you can get same functionality by enabling login block in the header region.

Comment: I moved it but it does not show up and I cleared cache too.

Comment: Are you logged out of the site before checking it. 
Assign block in the header region -> flush cache -> logout

Comment: Yes I did in the same sequence

Comment: try assigning it in some other region like content just to confirm.